# Django admin's default autocomplete_fields combined with Chained Foreign Key of smart-selects

Tags: django, django-smart-selects

I am using **Django 2.1.3**, **django-smart-selects 1.5.4** and three simple models for example Client, Billing Account and Order.

What needs to be done is upon **Order** creation the user should choose a **Client** (presuming that the count of all registered clients will be a large number) as an ***autocomplete_field***. Upon choosing Client there should be another select with all billing accounts associated for this client.

In **Order** i have related **Client** as a ForeignKey and **BillingAccount** as a ChainedForeignKey to **Client** using smart-selects as following:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    billing_account = ChainedForeignKey(BillingAccount, chained_field="client",
                                    chained_model_field="client",
                                    show_all=False,
                                    auto_choose=True,
                                    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                    null=True)
```

The problem is when the user chooses a given **Client**, the **BillingAccount** select wont autofill.

**Note:**
When **Client** is not associated in OrderAdmin's ***autocomplete_fields*** BillingAccount is filled as it should be with all accounts associated for this **Client**.

I wrote custom Ajax which is doing the trick for me but my question is:

**Is there something that I miss to include or django-smart-selects doesn't work with autocomplete_fields by default?**